# How to get rid of "REVERTING" in GIT

Tags: git

I did something wrong on my code and I searched some command to revert back to the previous version but things goes worser. I have no idea what to do to fix the problem. So scary~~~

I have tried many commands and no idea what I have used once I used 
git revert  to get back to normal working status. In this stage my code is working but how can I get back to master branch?

```
Now the terminal show: 

zswenjin:~/workspace/project_1 ((f9f01be...)|REVERTING) $ 


That is git log:
    commit f9f01bee8249770135e92dc6bc117c5033d3e349 (HEAD)
    Merge: 2a9bc0a 2bb5f7e
    Author: Louis
    Date:   Wed Aug 29 12:28:23 2018 +0000

        Merge branch 'master' into HEAD

    commit 2a9bc0a2110c1a35ab32504c16208305ee7ac895
    Author: Louis 
    Date:   Wed Aug 29 12:23:00 2018 +0000

        Revert "Revert "user now can edit and update their reviews""

        This reverts commit 37062450a252dcf2f22054e9b094ce97bb60ed6d.

    commit afd7b3a8f0fcbd89577bef1f473d0721138b0b3e
    Author: Louis
    Date:   Wed Aug 29 12:21:40 2018 +0000

        Revert "user now can edit and update their reviews"

        This reverts commit 5b7e703aafe1a5d745674eb2350cd4967a9d73a7.

    commit 2bb5f7ee26fff9ec2f8ec3653e87ae30a191e7e4 (github/master, master)
    Author: Louis 
    Date:   Wed Aug 29 11:46:20 2018 +0000

    just commit

    commit 466ce7f711bf38203be829424d960157638e8d4e
    Author: Louis
    Date:   Wed Aug 29 11:44:07 2018 +0000

    Revert "recover from disater"

    This reverts commit 1162459e513425da2ba22a82a7d787fb2cd8da79.



   commit 1162459e513425da2ba22a82a7d787fb2cd8da79
    Author: Louis
    Date:   Wed Aug 29 11:38:00 2018 +0000

        recover from disater

    commit 37062450a252dcf2f22054e9b094ce97bb60ed6d
    Author: Louis 
    Date:   Wed Aug 29 11:35:26 2018 +0000

        Revert "user now can edit and update their reviews"

        This reverts commit 5b7e703aafe1a5d745674eb2350cd4967a9d73a7.
```

git status shows:

```
HEAD detached from 5b7e703
You are currently reverting commit 3706245.
  (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php
        modified:   database/test.sql
        modified:   resources/views/includes/manufacturer/manufacturerDetail.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/includes/navBar/navBar.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/includes/products/productDetail.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/includes/products/updateProduct.blade.php
        new file:   resources/views/includes/reviews/editReview.blade.php
        modified:   resources/views/reviewDesc.blade.php

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   routes/web.php
```

Comment: try `git diff` ,and check which different you want to rollback.

Comment: what does `git status` tell you?

Comment: @rubenvb I've updated it in the post

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to get back to master:

You should be able to exit the "reverting" state by

```
git revert --abort
```

It appears you will then be in detached head state.  The information you've given doesn't tell us how you got into that state, or whether you have made any changes while in detached head (which could then be stored in unreachable commits).  If so, you might want to create a branch or tag before moving on, to ensure that those changes are recoverable later.

Furthermore at this point you might want to say

```
git status
```

to see if there are any uncommitted changes.

Once you're sure you want to go back to master, you should be able to

```
git checkout master
```

It's possible local uncommitted changes would interfere with this, in which case you'd have to decide whether to commit them, stash them, discard them, or postpone the checkout until later when you've done one of the above.

Answer (score 3):

As `git status` tells you, you have two options:

> You are currently reverting commit 3706245.
>     (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
>     (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

What you need to do depends on what you want to accomplish. Do you want to cancel the revert, do `git revert --abort`. Do you want to revert this commit, then fix the conflicts and do `git revert --continue`.

Comment: I run git revert --continue, but it shows:        routes/web.php
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Comment: And did you do what the message told you? The file `routes/web.php` will have conflict markers you'll need to process (either with a merge tool like kdiff3 or manually), after which you do `git add routes/web.php` followed by `git revert --continue`. This is happening because the code altered in your commit 3706245 has changed in the meantime, and the reverse patch doesn't apply cleanly anymore.